# How does Alexa compute bounce rate? Is it based on IP address and time period?

Tags: alexa, bounce-rate

I can't find detailed info how Alexa.com is counting bounce rate.

Is bounce rate computed only from first IP visit or from every page visit without any interaction? Can an IP only bounce once per day?

Example is here: https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/seznam.cz

Comment: I can say that the alexa's informations are not correct for Bounce rate : for example it's said for us BR: 100 % ... -)
there are also problems with pages and visitors by day.
Big differences with Google Analytics.

Answer (score 2):

The bounce rate is measured much the same way as you would see in any web analytics tool. In this case it is measured per visit/session.

Alexa's data is provided by users in the global data panel. These users are people who use Alex's browser extensions and plug-ins such as the Alexa's Toolbar.

Comment: So it isn't based on IP address, but rather based on a visitor using a particular browser.   How about Alexa's session timeout?  I know Google Analytics uses a 30 minutes session.

Comment: But what happens if I visit website 10x times a day and after load I leave page? It will count only one bounce rate or 10?